# BigInteger addition always 0

Tags: java, addition, biginteger, factorial

I have the following issue: when trying to add to a sum of BigIntegers the outcome remains 0.

Here is the code:

```
 public void NumberOfOutcomes(int x, int y){
   BigInteger first = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
   BigInteger second = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
   for(int i = 0; i <= (x / 2); i++){
       first.add( fac(x - i).divide((fac(x - 2*i).multiply(fac(i)))) );
       System.out.println("First " + first.add( fac(x - i).divide((fac(x - 2*i).multiply(fac(i)))) ));
    }

   for(int i = 0; i <= (y / 2); i++){
       second.add( fac(y - i).divide((fac(y - 2*i).multiply(fac(i)))) );
       System.out.println("Second " + second.add( fac(y - i).divide((fac(y - 2*i).multiply(fac(i)))) ));
    } 
   System.out.println("First " + first);
   System.out.println("Second " + second);
   System.out.println(first.multiply(second));
   }
```

Here `fac` is the factorial function.

Here is what comes on the terminal:

> points1.NumberOfOutcomes(2, 3) 
>   First 1 
>   First 1 
>   Second 1 
>   Second 2 
>   First 0 
>   Second 0 
>   0

Comment: `first.add(...)` doesn't change `first`.

Comment: I see, but what I can do about it?

Comment: btw, you can use `BigInteger.ZERO` instead of `BigInteger.valueOf(0)`

Comment: `first = first.add(...);`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because `BigInteger` is *immutable* which means that its value does not change. So `first.add(x)` will create *a new* `BigInteger` containing the computations result, i.e. just reassign the result to first, like `first = first.add(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `add` method of `BigInteger` class returns the sum of the operand and the value already stored in the the object itself. But it does not store the result in the object (first or second). 
It doesn't work in the same way as

```
first += value;
```

actually, you have to make it look like this:

```
first = first.add(value);
```