# BigInteger Factors in java

Tags: java

So i am trying to find all the factors of a large number i.e 10^15.Where am i going wrong?
I just input test cases then the large number and i need all the factors of that number.

this is my code

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = sc.nextInt();
        int blue[];
        int siize;
        BigInteger babe;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<test;i++){
            babe = sc.nextBigInteger();

            for(BigInteger j=BigInteger.ONE;j.compareTo(babe)<=0;j.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
                if(babe.mod(j).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){
                    System.out.print(j+" ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();     
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: Iterating 10^15 numbers will just take a rrrrrrrrrrrrreally long time. For _prime_ factors, you can speed up the process considerably by dividing the number to be tested by each factor you find until it is down to one. Once you have prime factors, you can get all factors as combinations of those.

Comment: You code is right, maybe would be better print out into a .txt file instead of console, and you just to have to wait..

Comment: or maybe you want to count the number of factor that has an specific number.

Comment: Well it outputs all 1's whats going on?

Comment: In the for loop, change it to j=j.add(BigInteger.ONE) because BigIntegers are immutable.

Comment: What do i need to do now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097093/biginteger-addition-always-0

Comment: Yes Thanks i did that but for a length of 14 digit number the factors are displaying only upto the length of 8 digit number ? oh its showing Time limit exceeded what should i do?

Comment: You should definitely follow @tobias_k's advice which is to avoid iterating over all the numbers up to n and start iterating over the primes up to sqrt(n) instead. See [BigInteger.nextProbablePrime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime())